4-pin BLDC (PC) fan and low-side load switching
I am trying to build a circuit where a STM32 microcontroller can control a PWM fan (well two fans in parallel). Because I also want the ability to fully power the fan off, I added a low side load switch.

According to the specs for the fan, there is a 3.3V pullup for the PWM pin on the fan's circuit board. My concern is that since the PWM pin is connected to the microcontroller, I am unsure of what happens when the MOSFET is switched off. I don't know how the fan's circuit is implemented so it's a black box to me. But isn't it possible that current from 12V could somehow leak back to the PWM pin?
I know high side switching would make this problem go away but I would like to stick with low side switching because of the lower RDS(on).

4-wire (and 3-wire) fans don't get along with low side switching so well. They have logic signals that are referenced to GND (tach, PWM) that will form 'sneak' paths when the GND is opened up. This will damage the fan.
Instead, use a high-side switch, which you can construct easily enough using a p-channel FET + level shifter FET. There’s plenty of low Rds(on) choices in p-channel FETs that are more than adequate for a fan, which in my experience will have current demands no more than 300mA (usually about 150mA - example.)
Knowing this, here's a couple of good, economical logic-level p-FET choices: On Semi FDN306P, Alpha+Omega AO3413. Both in SOT23-3, as are many other switching FETs. The FDN306P will have an Rds(on) of less than 30mOhm; the AO3413 is slightly higher at 50mOhm (assuming Vgs near -8V). At 150mA current, their IR drops (power loss) will be no worse than 4.5mV (0.7mW) or 7.5mV (1.1mW) for these FETs. Practically nothing really.
Here's how to use them with a level shifter (simulate it here):

A necessary detail: There is a voltage divider for the p-FET gate. This limits its Vgs to -7.2V (Vgs limit is +/-8V for these FETs.)
Want to reduce your cost further? Consider a PNP transistor.
Not as sensitive to cost? Consider using a high-side load switch IC. Some of these use p-FETs, while others use n-FETs and create gate drive voltage with an internal charge pump. Many offer overcurrent protection and fault monitoring.

PNP's burn up power so be careful, if the fan draws a significant amount of current.

The fan current isn’t that big to be a concern - 150mA per fan. I linked a datasheet for example.

Thank you, I ended up going with a high-side switch for the reasons you described (I looked at some teardowns of the fans and realized that it's an IC controller so floating ground is an issue). One thing I don't understand from your design is the voltage divider on Vgs. Source is at +12V and the gate is at +7.2V so isn't Vgs=-4.8V which is lower than Vgs(th)?

Gate is at 4.8V. The gate (4.8V) relative to source (12V) is -7.2V.

Sorry mixed up the numbers you're right Vgs=-7.2V but I am still confused. Vgs(th) is between -0.4V and -1V meaning we need voltage at the gate to be +11V or higher right?

The p-FET gate voltage needs to be at least one threshold voltage more negative than the source. The more negative it is, the harder the FET will turn on. But it can’t be more than -8V, which will damage the FET.
